# Is there a "natural" way to define a group operation on the set of size-$n$ subsets of a finite set?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, combinations

It is easy to define a group operation on the set of *all* subsets of a given finite set S of size n: merely take the exclusive-or (disjoint sum) of the two sets.  This is associative, the empty set is the identity, and each element is its own inverse.

Can one somehow similarly define a group operation on the set of subsets of a given size k?

Of course, if k=1, then one could use addition modulo n...

Suppose k = 2, and n = 4.  Is there some cute way to define the "sum" of {a,b} and {c,d} to
be another subset {e,f} that satisfies the group axioms?

(I'm looking for "natural" or "combinatorial" solutions; one can clearly provide an index or rank to each of the C(n,k) subsets, and then define a group somehow on these ranks, e.g. by addition modulo C(n,k). But this is not the sort of solutions I'd like to see...)

Comment: Interesting question, one thing which makes me think that any such construction would be a little artificial, is that for fixed $k$ the group with $n$ elements won't be in general a subgroup of the group with $n+1$ elements....

Comment: Also, I should point out that for $n=4$ and $k=2$ there are only two choices for your group: $S_3$ or $\mathbb Z/6 \mathbb Z$. And for each of those two, up to permutations, there are only few choices of choosing the isomorphism between your structure and the group. You can list all of them and see if any looks natural...

Answer (score 6):

No there is not.
Let $S$ be the set of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set $A$, $1\le k<n$.
If there were a group law $\circ$ on $S$ that deserved being called *natural*, then it would be invariant under the permutations of $S$ that are induced by the group $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ of permutations of $A$. Especially, this action of $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ must leave the neutral element of $(S,\circ)$ fixed. Since $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ acts transitively on $S$ and $|S|>1$, this is not possible.

Comment: This seems correct.  However, I would be interested in solutions that treated the elements of S unequally -- e.g. the elements of S are the integers 0 to n-1, and the "sum" operation on subsets of S took into account somehow the ordering of elements within S...

Comment: @user51534 Well, that's a different question altogether ...

Answer (score 1):

For $n=4$ and $k=2$ this is a very artificial natural construction :)

Let $\{1,2,3,5\}$ be the four elements. Then identify a set $\{ a, b \}$  with $a+b \pmod 6$, this gives a bijection from the set of two elements subsets to $\mathbb Z /6 \mathbb Z$.

The "natural" definition is the following:

$$\{a,b\}+ \{a',b'\}= \{c,d\}$$

where $\{ c,d \}$ is the only two elements subset of $\{ 1,2,3,5\}$ such that

$$a+b+a'+b'=c+d \pmod 6 \,.$$

The idea can be extended to all pairs  $(n,k)$ for which you can find a set $\{ a_1,..,a_n \}$ such that any two distinct $k$-elements subsets have different sums $\pmod{\binom{n}{k}}$.

Comment: Interesting!  Any idea on how to determine whether such sets a_i exist, or how to construct them, given n and k ??